# flex - cloned ComboBox class - down arrow gone (trying to fix drop off bottom of screen)

Tags: apache-flex

I have cloned the ComboBox class in order to fix the problem where a ComboBox at the bottom of a tab expands downwards and disappears off the bottom of the screen. I did this to apply the patch from http://craiggrummitt.wordpress.com/tag/combobox/. I had to copy "../styles/FocusStyles.as" etc into a project folder. also I copied ComboBox.png into a project folder.

The ComboBox does now open upwards, but there is no arrow button on the displayed combo. If I rename [IconFile("ComboBox.png")] to [IconFile("Garbage.png")] I get no error and the code still runs. There is no Garbage.png. Does this mean that the problem is that ComboBox.png displays the arrow button and the new class cannot locate this file, or is this just a red herring? tia.

Answer (score 0):

The [IconFile metadata](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html) is used by Flash Builder and is unrelated to runtime elements of the component.  I'll quote the docs:

> Identifies the filename for the icon that represents the component in
>   the Insert bar of Adobe Flex Builder. For more information, see
>   IconFile metadata tag.

If there is no arrow button on the ComboBox; it sounds like you may have improperly set the skin, or somehow disturbed functionality with our extension.  You'd have to share some code for us to help further.